# tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row: How to tell which column is calling me?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

Knowing which row is trivial, as I get the rowIndex parameter, but how do you find which column is calling your method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get passed an `NSTableColumn` object in the `tableColumn` parameter.  You can use its `identifier` method to tell them apart.

Answer (score 0):

To be a bit more specific for those who stumble on this. In the interface builder select each of your NSTableColumn and in the attributes enter an identifier for referencing the column in your code, e.g. "FirstColumn". 
Then in your code you can find which column is being requested with:

```
if let id = objectValueFor?.identifier.rawValue {
    switch id {
        case "FirstColumn":
           // your code goes here
```